# Check if all the pairs in a dict also exist in another dict, possibly with equal or lower corresponding values

Tags: python

I have a dict and a string here, with the dict containing char-count as key value pair. I want to check if the all the characters in the string are completely contained in the dict.

This means that the dict should contain all the chars of the string, with their counts less than or equal to their corresponding values in the dict.

```
def isValidWord(strng, dct):
    """
    Returns True if strng is entirely
    composed of letters in the dct.
    Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or dct.
    """

    d={}
    for x in strng:
        d[x]=d.get(x,0)

    for x in d:
        if d[x]> dct.get(x,0):
            return False

    return True
```

It seems to work well for most cases, but for some cases it doesn't. For example -

```
isValidWord('chayote', {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'u': 2, 't': 2, 'y': 1, 'h': 1, 'z': 1, 
'o': 2})
```

This gives output `True`, however the correct output is `False`.
This is because there is no `e` in the dict.

Where is the bug here ? And how can I check if all the pairs in a dict also exist in another dict, possibly with equal or lower corresponding values (of keys).

Comment: When you say `d[x]=d.get(x,0)`, did you mean it to be `d[x]=d.get(x,0) + 1`?

Comment: Oops.. Yups Corrected that !!

Comment: Does it now exhibit the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant for the line

```
d[x]=d.get(x,0)
```

to be

```
d[x]=d.get(x,0) + 1
```

otherwise, all the values in the dictionary would be `0`, and the function would always return `True` (unless the string were empty or any values in the given dictionary were `0`.

Also note that it would be easier to use `collections.Counter` for your first loop:

```
d = collections.Counter(strng)
```

As for your question of testing whether one dict is in another, you can do:

```
all(k in dct and v < dct[k] for k, v in d.items())
```

Comment: Yeah.. thanks for the bug.. But the main question was how do I check if one dict is subset of another dict ??